# Is there any option to run SQLite flutter for web build?

Tags: sqlite, web, flutter

I wrought some example code from [flutter sqllite example code](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/persistence/sqlite) and now i wonder if there is any possibility to run the same code with that packages to build app for web?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Sqflite does not support Flutter Web for now, but we have a package which is very similar Moor: https://pub.dev/packages/moor
You can try it and it should meet your need.

An issue is currently opened on sqflite GitHub: https://github.com/tekartik/sqflite/issues/212 you can see the progress if you want to.

Comment: As of now, [moor](https://pub.dev/packages/moor) is discontinued, and has been replaced by [drift](https://pub.dev/packages/drift)

Answer (score 1):

As Sqlite doesn't have web support. There is a package with all the support. You can use Hive DB instead and also this package is dart 3 ready.

https://pub.dev/packages/hive